# Web framework with really good admin/CRUD module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, playframework, web2py

Lot's (if not most) of the current Web frameworks provide an admin module for basic CRUD operations, but I find the ones I know usually very limited...

So, my question is, **which Web framework out there provide the best administration backend**?

By *the best*, I mean namely:

- **Domain objects that can be heavily polymorphic.** Attributes/relations defined in a class appear when editing a record/instance of any of it's subclasses (and sub-subclasses, and sub-sub-subclasses, etc).
- **Abstract classes.** It's ok to have abstract classes anywhere in the domain classes' hierarchy. Their attributes and relations also show in the records/instances of all descending classes.
- **Relations**. Allow to edit (out-of-the-box) the records/instances that have many-to-many relations, and relations with associative classes (e.g., django calls these [intermediate models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships))
- **Extension.** Allow to extend the admin so that we can use our own "UI controls" for specific domain objects. Some information is just too "exquisite" for an out-of-the-box form-based control to work in a suitable way.
- **UI Components.** Instead of having to choose between using all of it or none of it, it'd be nice to have generic "UI controls" that one could reuse from within any page of the website, to edit specific domain objects.

Programming language is not an issue at this point, although I lean towards the languages (or frameworks) that allow me to express the most information at the domain model level (and that the admin module can then use to give me a richer UI).

Answer (score 4):

I've been playing with Active Admin and Rails Admin for a couple of Rails 3.1 projects I am working on. While both are nice, I've migrated more and more to Rails Admin. I've found it easy to customize, it does a very nice job with associated models, and has a great default UI.

[Rails Admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin)

Comment: I don't know anything yet about RailsAdmin, but I've read a few things about ActiveAdmin. It doesn't seem to be very sophisticated though... How well would you say it behaves with polymorphic domain objects, and the other features that I've talked about?

Comment: I have not yet had the chance to incorporate a project with a true polymorphic association in RailsAdmin, however, when I read through their docs, they do "support" such associations. I apologize for not having a better response on that point!

Comment: Filipe - I'm actually integrating/adding some polymorphic models into a site today that uses RailsAdmin. I'll post back how it does this afternoon ... just in case you or someone reading this question/thread later wants to know!

Comment: To follow  up, RailsAdmin works well with the polymorphic model I added today. Once I had the model set up correctly, all I had to do was customize the form fields in the initializers/rails_admin.rb and I was good to go!

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! Sounds promising. Just wondering: are you creating several levels of inheritance or just one? Suppose you are editing a record/instance of a subclass, at the parent class level, does it show all the attributes/relations of the subclass too?

Comment: It does! My app is for managing a basketball team (I'm also a high school coach). Two relevant parent models are: Player and Coach. There are two, in this case, polymorphic models they use: Address (addressable) and Contact (contactable). When I'm on a player's or coach's admin page, I can add or edit an Address (or Contact) completely from this form, including selecting the 'contactable' aspects of it. Hope that helps!

Comment: ActiveAdmin has become really quite sophisticated of late. I'm not a wild fan of Arbre, but I do like the ease of use of the gem.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely good old WebObjects with it rule system called DirectToWeb. It generates everything at runtime based on rules. By default it can display all your entity's properties and relationships.

I guess that every current web framework will offer something like scaffolding, but often times, the work begins as soon as you change your model.

Check out this [post](http://davidleber.net/?p=402) and this [teaser](http://files.me.com/dav1d/0v1da8.mov) about the latest DirectToWeb-based framework, ERModern. You use nearly zero code for what you see in the video and you can build entire applications around it. It was sponsored by the iTunes team.

Edit for your bullet points:

- **Abstract classes and domain objects that can be heavily polymorphic** - You handle these using rules.
- **Editing relations** - No problem, it only depends on the design of your components. If you use ERModern, you get this for free.
- **Generic UI components** - This is exactly how DirectToWeb works. You use (or define your own) generic components that display themselves according to the current entity (an object inheriting from EOEnterpriseObject) and the rules that fired for the current state (the D2WContext, essentially a big dictionary).

You can see all of this in action in the 45 minutes long [ERModern Intro Video](http://www.wocommunity.org/podcasts/ERModernDirectToWebIntro.mov).

Comment: WebObjects looks interesting. It looks like it follows an [Adaptive Object-Model](http://adaptiveobjectmodel.com/) architecture, which sounds great. But the learning curve seems a little hard, and I wish it had a quicker hack-refresh cycle, like you get with django, rails and play!. I realize I haven't mentioned these "features" in the question... and their not the key thing here, but they end up being important too of course.

Comment: About the scaffolding: I see some of the current frameworks doing everything dynamically (i.e., without scaffolding). I know Django uses a dynamic approach, and that Rails uses a scaffolding approach (although apparently theres now ActiveAdmin and RailsAdmin, which take a dynamic approach too).

Comment: Anyway, I will definitely look more into it. From your experience, how well would you say it satisfies each of my bullet points?

Comment: I added the answers to your bullet points questions. Regarding the hacking cycle, when you start your WebObjects app in Eclipse's debug mode, you can change code and see the results immediately. There's also a JRebel plug-in available which makes it even quicker. Also, a WebObjects app starts much fast than a JEE app.

Comment: And yes, WebObjects has a somewhat steep learning curve. Except when you know Cocoa, then most concepts will be familiar to you. For example CoreData was derived from WebObject's EOF.

Comment: Sigh. I've used this kind of architecture in the past, and I know the benefits can be huge. But it's taking me quite a while to feel minimally productive with WOs. I've watched the videos and tried to experiment a bit with it, but I'm really taking very long to do stuff that I'd expect to be simple. I guess it's that steep learning curve showing itself... and it kinda puts me off of exploring it further.

Comment: I don't blame you, it's one of the reasons I wouldn't use it in a startup. Luckily this problem has been identified within the community, I hope it will be improved in the future. But thanks for checking it out!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an easy question to answer.

You never specify what language you want to use, and you named some features, but how much of these features do you want.

I mean I could suggest a number of frameworks and tools for ASP.Net MVC or Web Forms but what if you're a PHP developer or a Java developer?

I could suggest SharePoint (and I generally dislike sharepoint, but everything you want is in SharePoint), but then the question to ask is.

How much flexibility and freedom do you want to customize or how much do you want the framework to do and you just be a code monkey.

So I will give you just my opinion.

I use ASP.Net MVC for my custom apps.  It does all of what you want and allows me the most freedom to create and extend with tools if I so to do so.  Plus out of the box there's a user databse with roles I can easily create out of the boss once I run the app for the first time.

Also CRUD is completely easy and straight forward out of the box.  just check it out http://www.asp.net/mvc there's a tutorial section that goes through what you're wanting that you could complete in half a day.

Then there are some OR/M like NHibernate, Entity Framework, Subsonic use www.google.com to find tutorials for these if you're not familiar with them.

Then there's SharePoint it has a learning curve but once you get past it it's pretty straight forward as it's easy to pinpoint bugs, focus on the business logic and not worry aobut data base schema (as you don't even need to touch a database).

Comment: Hi Carl. I think you've missed a couple of things in my question. I'm specifically asking this independently from language, as I'm willing to adapt to any language if there's a framework for it that really hits the sweet spot for me. The thing that I'm having a harder trouble finding (and that the question focuses on) is a good auto-created backend system, like the one that Rails or Django provide. I may be wrong, but I don't think ASP.Net MVC even provides any of that, does it?

Comment: Not many in MVC.  http://orchardproject.net/docs/Getting-Started.ashx  But there is Orchard.  AtomicCMS, and other community driven on codeplex, do a good search.  I usually prefer to start with just a language and do everything else myself.  Gives met he freedom.

Comment: Yes, the tricky thing is to get the freedom while still having a lot of the work already done for you. But unfortunately neither Orchard nor AtomicCMS seem to be even near of the kind of framework I'm searching for...

Answer (score 0):

I love WebObjects.

`WebObjects` -> `EntityModeler` -> `Wonder` -> `ERD2WModernLook` -> `ERAttachment` --> `ERRest`

Bam. Done.